# grep or awk - how to return line if column 1 and 3 have the same value

Tags: perl, awk, grep

I have a tab delimited file and I want the output to have the entire line in my file if values in column 1 are the same as the values in column 3. Having very limited knowledge in perl and linux, this is as close as I came to a solution.

File example

```
Apple   Sugar   Apple    
Apple   Butter  Orange   
Raisins Flour   Orange   
Orange Butter  Orange
```

The results would be:

```
Apple Sugar Apple   
Orange Butter Orange
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh  

awk '{    
    prev=$0; f1=$1; f3=$3;    
    getline    
    if ($1 == $3) {    
        print prev    
        print    
    }'    
} myfilename
```

I am sure that there is an easier solution to it. Maybe even a grep or awk on the command line. But that was the only code I could find that seemed to give me my solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It's easy with `awk`:

```
awk '$1 == $3' myfile
```

The default action is to print out the record, so if fields 1 and 3 are equal, that's what will happen.

Comment: Same in Perl: `perl -lane'print if $F[0] eq $F[2]' myfile`

Comment: +1 as this is the right solution (once you add `-F'\t'` to it). @user2795815 Do not use any of the grep solutions as they will fail cryptically for some input values. For example, try them with a 2-line input file where the first line is `a good a` and the second is `a bad aa` (tab-separated per your requirement).

Answer (score 5):

#### Using `awk`

`awk` is the tool for the job:

```
awk '$1 == $3'
```

If your fields in the data are strictly tab separated and may contain blanks, then you will need to specify the field separator explicitly:

```
awk -F'\t' '$1 == $3'
```

(where the The `\t` represents a tab; you may have to type <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or even <kbd>Control-V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>) to get it into the string).

#### Using `grep`

You can do it with `grep`, but you don't want to do it with `grep`:

```
grep -E '([A-Za-z]+)\t[A-Za-z]+\t\1'
```

The key part of the regex is the `\1` which means 'the same value as the first captured string.

You might even go through gyrations like this in `bash`:

```
grep -E $'([A-Za-z]+)\t[A-Za-z]+\t\\1'
```

You could simplify life by noting (assuming) there are no spaces within fields:

```
grep -E '([A-Za-z]+)[[:space:]]+[A-Za-z]+[[:space:]]+\1'
```

As noted in one of the comments, I didn't put a `$` at the end of the search pattern; it would be feasible (though the data would have to be cleaned up to contain tabs and drop trailing blanks), so that 'Good Noise GoodBad' would not be picked up.  There are other ways to do it, and you can make the regex more and more complex to handle more possible situations.  But those only go to emphasize that the `awk` solution is better; `awk` deals with the details automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep`:

`grep -P "([^\t]+)\t[^\t]+\t\1" inFile`